# ECCN (Export Control Classification Number) for CEFSharp

Tags: cefsharp, eccn

We are using CEFSharp and have a question about US export regulations for our software. Do CEFSharp have a ECCN (Export Control Classification Number) assigned for this product and a corresponding license type?

If the product does not contain or use any encryption or cryptography functions when running on a (at end user) system the ECCN is not required (see requirements for ECCN https://www.bis.doc.gov/index.php/licensing/commerce-control-list-classification/export-control-classification-number-eccn ).

If CEFSharp creators could give some information about this it would be very helpful.

Comment: I'm the current CefSharp maintainer and I've never heard of ECCN. I'm also not from the US. CefSharp itself is just a wrapper around the Chromium embedded framework,  on the CEF support forum I don't See any questions referencing ECCN. https://magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php You can ask there to see if anyone has some information.

Comment: @amaitland Thank you. I have asked CEF and they also don't know. It may be mainly Chromium that needs it if their code has the cryptography functions.